# Minimum time for promises

Tags: javascript

I'd like to have a minimum time applied to async logic. Ultimately this is for situations where you want to show a loading animation for at least 2-3 seconds. Maybe there's a better strategy?

**Question:** Why does `console.log("Finish")` never trigger?

**Question:** Why does it seem time is not being applied, e.g. "99999" occurs instantly?

Below is based on [this article](http://mitchvollebregt.com/snippets-js-promise-minimum-execution-time/).

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/LYbZZGz?editors=1011)

```js
    onInit = async formData => {
      console.log("-------------------")
      console.log("Start")
      await executeAtLeast(3000, doesSomething)
      console.log("Finish")
    }
    
    onInit()
    
    
    
    function doesSomething() {
      console.log("Job being processed")
    }
    
    function promiseAllReflect(promises = []) { 
        const reflect = promise => promise.then(
            value => ({ value, status: 'fulfilled' }),
            error => ({ error, status: 'rejected' }),
        )
    
        return Promise.all(promises.map(reflect))
    }
    
    function executeAtLeast(time, func, funcArgs = []) {  
        return promiseAllReflect([
            new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time)), 
              func(...funcArgs)
        ])
    }
```

Comment: `doSomething` doesn't return a promise, so this code throws an error.

Comment: As mentioned in the first comment, `doSomething` doesn't returns a `Promise`, so the array passed to `promiseAllReflect` function contains a `Promise` at its first index and `undefined` at its second index. Inside the callback function of `map()` method, you are calling `promise.then(...)` which should give you an error, something like "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined". Try wrapping the code in `onInit` function in a `try-catch` block to catch the error.